# Kafka Stream grouping on KTable value field

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a use case where my KTable is like this.

**KTable** : orderTable

**Key:Value**

`{123} :  {id1,12}`

`{124} : {id2,10}`

`{125} :  {id1,5}`

`{126} :  {id2,11}`

**KTable** : `orderByIdTable`  `=>` This table would be on groupBy Value `field` `(id)` and count column value will have sum of `id1=(12+5)` , `id2=(10+11)`

**Key   :  Value**

`{id1}  : {17}`

`{id2}  : {21}`

```
         final KTable<String, Order> orderTable = builder.table("order-topic");
         Don't know how to do this further.....
         final KTable<String,Long> orderByIdTable = ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code example (using only Java primitive types, which made it quicker for me to put together) that demonstrates how to re-key aka re-partition a KTable, resulting in new KTable. You should be able to easily adapt it to your example of turning a `KTable<String, Order>` into a `KTable<String, Long>`.

Personally, I'd pick  Variant 2 for your use case.

Examples below. **Not fully tested**, it might be that tombstone records (messages with a non-null key but a null value, which indicate that the key should be removed from the table) are not handled properly.

```java
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
final KTable<Integer, String> table = builder.table(inputTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.String()));

// Variant 1 (https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#option-1-write-kstream-to-ak-read-back-as-ktable)
// Here, we re-key the KTable, write the results to a new topic, and then re-read that topic into a new KTable.
table
    .toStream()
    .map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(value, key))
    .to(outputTopic1, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Integer()));
KTable<String, Integer> rekeyedTable1 =
    builder.table(outputTopic1, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Integer()));

// Variant 2 (https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#option-2-perform-a-dummy-aggregation)
// Here, we re-key the KTable (resulting in a KGroupedTable), and then perform a dummy aggregation to turn the
// KGroupedTable into a KTable.
final KTable<String, Integer> rekeyedTable2 =
    table
        .groupBy(
            (key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(value, key),
            Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Integer())
        )
        // Dummy aggregation
        .reduce(
            (aggValue, newValue) -> newValue, /* adder */
            (aggValue, oldValue) -> oldValue  /* subtractor */
        );
rekeyedTable2.toStream().to(outputTopic2, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Integer()));
```

Comment: How should I do sum of value's second field using `Variant 1`? I don't see any way where I have reference to old value.

Comment: Variant 1 sound unnecessary for this use case. As you want to aggregate, you should use `KTable.groupBy(...).aggregate(...)` (or `.reduce(..)`).

Comment: Personally I'd pick Variant 2.  For Variant 1, your use case would also work but the roundtrip to a second Kafka topic would be unnecessary, and Variant 1 would have some overhead compared to Variant 2.